# how to get c, c++, and java compilers in linux ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, compiling, software-installation

I installed Ubuntu on windows 7 using wubi software, now i want to practice c,c++ and java programming. As I am new to Ubuntu, I don't know how to get those compilers. I saw so many comments on google search. there they mentioned commands `sudo apt-get install build essential`, but i don't have cd - I installed ubuntu through wubi. So can you please guide me how to get those.

Kind Regards
Munisekhar

Answer (score 0):

Just open a terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

That should do it.